# Get multiple fields back?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to get multiple properties back for a command within parentheses? Consider the following code.

```
$service = (get-service -name 'wuauserv')
$service.Name # I get the name property back
```

But what If I wanted to get more than one property. For example below:

```
$service.Name,Status
```

Why doesn't this work? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to simply display it, you can use `select-object -property Name,Status`. If you want to parse those values, it will be different. If you just type in `$service` after running the command, you should see it has 3 properties attached to it

Answer (score 1):

What you are dealing with is the concept of how PowerShell handles outputting information and the pipeline. When you collect `Get-Service` into the variable `$service`, you are storing an object that has multiple properties.

To work with the properties of a given object (one or many) you utilize `Select-Object` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/Select-Object)). Whether you are dealing with that variable contents or directly with the output from `Get-Service` you have to pipe the output to `Select-Object` to retrieve one to many properties. You can do this multiple ways. PowerShell works on positions when it comes to parameters, so the position 0 parameter for `Select-Object` is `-Property`. All of the following are equivalent, and just various ways to get the same result:

```
$proc = Get-Service -Name mssql*
$proc | Select-Object Name, DisplayName

$proc = Get-Service -Name mssql*
Select-Object -Property Name, DisplayName -InputObject $proc

Get-Service -Name mssql* | Select-Object Name, DisplayName
```

If you want your variable to only contain a given set of properties then you would also utilize `Select-Object`:

```
$proc = Get-Service -Name mssql* | Select-Object Name, DisplayName
$proc
```

Output Example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you do `$Service.Name` it returns a the expanded property, how would you return the expanded property for multiple properties?

```
PS H:\> $Service = (Get-Service -name 'wuauserv')
PS H:\> $Service | Select-Object Name, Status

Name      Status
----      ------
wuauserv Stopped
```

Notice how they are not an expanded property.

```
PS H:\> $service.Name
wuauserv
PS H:\> $service | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
wuauserv
```

Trying to expand multiple properties will end up with an error as the method cannot accept multiple arguments (Name, Status).